# SWIFT 2.0: Writing log data to local folder

Tags: logging, path, directory, local

I'm trying to follow my code without using the debugger. When executed, the current folder is different than when using XCode environment. So I like to get output. Because I'm not executing in Terminal there is no output window. So I try to direct it to a log file.

```
func writeToDocumentsFile(fileNameOnly:String, value:String) -> Bool {
    let path = getDocPath(fileNameOnly)
    var error:NSError?
    do {
        try value.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }
    return error == 0
}
```

Here I get an error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The folder “Log1.txt” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x600000260d80 {NSFilePath=/Users/dirk/Documents/Users/dirk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DSRenamer4-gopilcfgcwfqutabrktbxqhjornv/Build/Products/Debug/Log1.txt, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000000549d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"})
```

Using a small wrapper function:

```
var output = ""

func LogToFile(file : String, text : String ) {

    output += text + "\r\n"

    writeToDocumentsFile(file, value: output)
}
```

this call fails:

```
LogToFile(getCurrentPath("Log1.txt"), text: ">1>check plistfile >\(path)<")
```

Any idea? Of cause there is no such file. This file should be created with writing the text in it.